# caching data into files on server rather than do SQL calls. Faster, slower?

Tags: caching, data-storage

I know this poses a security risk, but I was just wondering out of principle; is storing some non-sensitive, constantly accessed data in a file (On the same server) quicker than pulling this information every time from the database?

Comment: It depends.  If the database is in the RAM, it might be quicker to pull it out of the database.  If the data is constantly accessed, then you can place it statically in an html file.

Comment: It is a very large database and as far as I know we don't have memCache installed on it (run by a different department)

Comment: You might consider installing memCache if you can, that would speed things up quite a bit.

Comment: Too much red tape to cut through when its managed by someone else. We will get that installed eventually, but for now gotta work around that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on a variety of different aspects. To name a view:

- Is the data that's being fetched from the database *easily* accessible? That is, are the queries needed to generate the answer optimized (indexes, query caching possible)?
- Are you postproccessing the data after pulling it from the database? If so, is it possible to cache the outcome or impossible due to some kind of dynamic properties (e.g. a monetary value that needs to be translated to another currency with real time excachange rates)?
- Assuming you are going to cache the data in a file, is it possible to write it to an in-memory filesystem rather than constantly hitting the disk.
- How often do these data change? Regularly? Ever so often?

All these (and a couple of more once you start thinking) aspects you would have to take into consideration.